# C# - failed parse exception?

Tags: c#, .net

I am  writing a program in C#, and I want to catch exceptions caused by converting "" (null) to int. What is the exception's name?

**EDIT:**
I'm not sure I can show the full code... But I'm sure you don't need the full code, so:

```cs
int num1 = Int32.Parse(number1.Text);
int num2 = Int32.Parse(number2.Text);
```

Comment: Why would you want to know the name of the exception? Are you going to catch it? (Hope not...)

Comment: Also, note the "" and null are different things.

Comment: Would checking for false instead of handling an exception be a problem?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**If you can avoid it, do not code by exception!**

The exception name you are looking for is called a `FormatException`.

However, it would be smarter to first do a `TryParse` on the object you are attempting to parse, e.g.

```
int value;
if(!int.TryParse("1", out value))
{
    // You caught it without throwing an exception.
}
```

Comment: Why not "if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(i))" first? Seriously, you don't want to even incur the TryParse. Even if you do it a thousand times and only fail once, the if statement before the TryParse will be faster.

Comment: @devinb: Add two extra lines of code just to make it 10ms faster? Sounds like unnecessary micro-optimization to me...

Comment: @George, it would be great if you backed up claims like "If you can avoid it, do not code by exception" and "it would be smarter" with some cold facts :-)

Comment: @Heinzi First of all - 10ms is a shitload of time in terms of programming. Also, 10ms will accumulate in seconds quite fast. You just need a hundred bad decisions costing you 10ms over the span of few months to slow down your whole app with 1 second. And that's how some websites load every page for 2-5 seconds - because someone (or many people) said "pff, I'm not gonna write 2 more lines to save a few ms" too many times.

Comment: @BojidarStanchev: Indeed. In that case you need to compare the lost sales due to the 1 second delay to the additional development and maintenance cost of having all those micro-optimizations in your code. Which one "wins" depends on your business case.

Answer (score 14):

You are going to get a [FormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx) if a parse fails.  Why not use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead?

Answer (score 11):

As a side note, a simple way to find out the exception is to run it. When you encounter the error, it'll give you the exception name.

Answer (score 6):

Let's have a look [at the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) (which is a much cleaner solution that "trying it out"):

> public static int Parse(string s)
>
> [...]
>
> Exceptions:
>
> - `ArgumentNullException`: s is null.
> - `FormatException`: s is not in the correct format.

This should answer your question. As others have already mentioned, maybe you are asking the wrong question and want to use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're using to do the conversion. For example, [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) will throw `ArgumentNullException`, `FormatException`, or `OverflowException`. Odds are it's `ArgumentNullException` you're looking for, but if that's an empty string rather than a null reference, it's probably going to be `FormatException`

Answer (score 0):

When the exception fires you can see it's type.  The smart thing to do is handle that case and display a graceful message to your user if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking to get a `System.InvalidCastException`, although I think that'll depend on how you try to perform the conversion.

That said, wouldn't it be quicker/easier to simply write the code and try it yourself? Particularly as you haven't specified *how* you'll be performing the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it. This code:

```
int.Parse("");
```

Throws a FormatException.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are expensive. You should use int.TryParse.  It will return the boolean false if the conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToInt32 does not throw a format exception ("input string is not in the correct format") on a null string. You can use that if it is acceptable for the result to be a 0 for a null string. (still pukes on empty string though)

```
        string s = null;
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(s);
```

But if you expect a number to be in the box, you should either use TryParse (as was suggested) or a Validator of some kind to inform the user that they need to enter a number.