# How do you make it so the program instead of crashing, it can display something different when you enter a string value or wrong format

Tags: c#, if-statement, parsing, console

I get this error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Code:

```
namespace ExcerciseOne
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Enter A Number 1 - 10");

            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            int parsedInput = int.Parse(userInput);

            if (parsedInput > 0 & parsedInput < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valid");
            }
            else if ( parsedInput <= 0) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366684/c-sharp-failed-parse-exception

Comment: Not every string can be parsed into `int` (e.g. if user enter "bla-bla-bla")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int.TryParse()` instead like so:

```
namespace ExcerciseOne
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Enter A Number 1 - 10");

            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if(int.TryParse(out var userInput)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valid");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TryParse returns true if the input can be parsed as an int and false if it cannot be parsed without throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

Many a string can't reprsent `int` value (e.g. `"Abracadabra"` string); to detect such cases
I suggest using `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello Enter A Number 1 - 10");

    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
         
    if (int.TryParse(userInput, out int parsedInput) && 
        parsedInput > 0 && 
        parsedInput < 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valid");
    }
    else  
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
    }
}
```

Here `userInut` is valid (and parsed into `parsedInput`) if and only if:

- `userInput` is parsed into `int parsedInt` - `int.TryParse`
- Parsed value is greater than `0`
- Parsed value is less than `10`

It seems, that you don't want the second condition `if (parsedInt < 0)`: if `userInput` is not valid then it's invalid.

Another but chance possibility is to check if string has one symbol which is within `'1'` and `'9'`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello Enter A Number 1 - 10");

    // Trim(): let tolerate leading and trailing spaces 
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
         
    if (userInput.Length == '1' && userInput[0] >= '1' && userInput[0] <= '9')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Valid");
    }
    else  
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Int.TryParse()` is one way to acheive this, but I might say using a try catch block here would be a better way to achieve this, especially because it allows you to give the user more information about what went wrong.

```
namespace ExcerciseOne
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello Enter A Number 1 - 10");    

            string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            try 
            {
                int parsedInput = int.Parse(userInput);

                if (parsedInput > 0 & parsedInput < 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Valid");
                }
                else if ( parsedInput <= 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input was not a number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's plenty wrong with this advice, especially given to someone who's just starting to learn as OP clearly is: 1) Catching exceptions is expensive. The exception is being thrown from within `int.Parse`, so it has to unwind the call stack, and that's not free. If you can avoid that, you should. 2) Catching the exception and ignoring the message gives you no more information that you would have using `int.TryParse`. [...]

Comment: Even if you weren't ignoring the exception -- which is `FormatException`, by the way -- it just says "Input string was not in a correct format." which is less helpful than any message you would want to display to the user. 3) Speaking of `FormatException`, you should be catching that instead `Exception`, if you had to catch an exception. Any other exception that it might throw, now or in the future, would not be something you know how to handle.  Catch only what you know how to handle.

Comment: I will concede that I should have caught a `FormatException` instead of a generic `Exception`. However, please see Microsofts documentation on best practices for exceptions. It clearly states that you should wrap code that could throw an exception within a try catch block.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#use-trycatchfinally-blocks-to-recover-from-errors-or-release-resources

Comment: That's *IF* the code could throw an exception. Using `int.TryParse` means it won't throw `FormatException`. And if, in the future, it could throw some other exception, you shouldn't be catching it because you can't possibly know how to handle it, so there's no point in a try/catch for that.

Comment: `int.TryParse` is more robust, but as I mentioned in my answer, you can't do as much with it as you could a try/catch. The OPs code has an ambiguous space for numbers that are greater than or equal to ten. Where it's not printing invalid for that, we don't know what the OP wants it to do, so I gave them the solution that leaves the most possibilities open. The slight inefficiency in throwing an exception is made up for in the flexibility it adds. Premature optimization causes more problems than anything.

Comment: The range test is unrelated to the exception handling for unparsable input. Granted, one of the other answers don't show that part of it because it was just addressing the exception OP was getting. And the other should have had them as separate tests so they could have different messages. But your answer does not follow best practices, not even those in the document you linked.

Comment: It says: *"For conditions that are likely to occur but might trigger an exception, consider handling them in a way that will avoid the exception."* Thus, `int.TryParse`.

Comment: I would disagree that the range test is unrelated, but it comes down to what exactly the OP wants the code to do. I had made an assumption that more was being done than what we saw. If what we see is all that's being done, then `int.TryParse` is definitely the correct answer. When coding, I've been taught to leave your options open first, and optimize second, as it leads to cleaner architecture. That's not what the question was about though, you're right. I'll humbly accept the fact that I was trying to go beyond the scope of the question, which is wrong. Thank you for being patient!

Comment: It can be difficult to know when to look at the question as asked and when to try to look deeper. There's no hard/fast rule for the latter, but it's often because it's an X/Y problem or the asker is confused on something more fundamental than the question states. This one was more straight-forward. I commend you on taking this as a learning opportunity.